Changing v-text-field default error color through SASS variables doesn't work
I'm trying to change v-text-field default error color. By looking at the documentation it should be possible by changing $field-error-color SASS variable. It will change all inputs default error color, but it's ok with me.
I followed what was written here and created my settings.scss
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $field-error-color: rgb(var(--v-theme-error-700))
);

The color doesn't change, though. What am I doing wrong?
P.S. code sandbox here.

$field-error-color variable exists but seems to not be used in the style, which looks like a bug that needs to be reported.
The solution is to override the rules in main style file:
.v-field--error:not(.v-field--disabled) .v-field__outline,
.v-field--error:not(.v-field--disabled) .v-label.v-field-label {
  color: rgb(var(--v-theme-error-700))
}


I've tried making sense out of their documentation and what you tried should work. My suggestion would be to ask on their forum (if they have one) or open an issue against their repo.
Meanwhile, you could override the value of --v-theme-error with the one of --v-theme-error-700 for all fields in an error state by adding this to your main.scss:
.v-field--error:not(.v-field--disabled) {
  --v-theme-error: var(--v-theme-error-700);
}

See it working.
